# How can I convert a vector of ints to be a vector of strings using STL algorithms?

Tags: c++, algorithm, transform, stdvector, std

For example, I would need `{20,6,143}` to become `{"20","6","143"}`.

Comment: Loop over your vector, for each int in it, use `std::to_string` to convert it to a string, and push it into a vector of strings.

Answer (score 3):

Simply using a range-based for-loop you could iterate through the *vector of integers* and using  [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) you could convert each element to string and store to the new *vector of strings*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> vec{ 20,6,143 };
   std::vector<std::string> strVec;
   strVec.reserve(vec.size());  // reserve memory for unwanted reallocations

   for (int element : vec)
      strVec.emplace_back(std::to_string(element));

   for (const auto& str : strVec)
      std::cout << str << " ";

}
```

**([See live online](https://godbolt.org/z/4oM_MD))**

---

Alternatively using [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), you could transform *the vector of integers* as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> // std::transform
#include <iterator>  // std::cbegin

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> vec{ 20,6,143 };
   std::vector<std::string> strVec;
   strVec.reserve(vec.size());  // reserve memory for unwanted reallocations

   std::transform(std::cbegin(vec), std::cend(vec),
      std::back_inserter(strVec), // insert to the back of strVec
      [](const int element) { return std::to_string(element);}
   );

   for (const auto& str : strVec)
      std::cout << str << " ";
}
```

**([See live online](https://godbolt.org/z/5DPU6a))**

Answer (score 2):

[std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) combined with [std::to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) should do the trick.